# Выбор загрузчика

Tags: linux, администрирование, железо

Привет всем!

Есть у меня очень старый netbook и очень старая флешка с допотопной gentoo (rescuecd), так вот gentoo с неё замечательно загружается на этом нетбуке. Так же есть у меня новая флешка и я пытаюсь записать на неё debian (Пробовал с помощью rufus, unetbootin, dd) - но при попытках нетбук отвечает No bootable device, хотя эта новая флешка вполне себе определяется нетбуком. Я подозреваю, что мне нужен какой-то допотпный загрузчик как на флешке с gentoo (я записывал её лет 5-6 назад).

**UPD**: Если с помощью dd снять образ со старой флешки и записать её на новую - система с неё загружается.

Может подскажете чего делать в такой неловкой ситуации?

Comment: Убедитесь, что образ создан с поддержкой legacy boot.

Answer (score 0):

Сумел записать загрузчик отдельно с помощью [WinSetupFromUSB](http://www.winsetupfromusb.com/files/download-info/winsetupfromusb-1-8-exe/) и с помощью него загрузил debian.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего надо сделать раздел с образом активным.

```
fdisk
```

`a`   переключение флага загрузки